# como mostrar el valor de un checkbox

Tags: php, html

mi problema es que estoy utilizando un checkbox , ya tengo hecho el botón guardar y efectivamente si guarda todos los datos ,el problema surge con el botón mostrar me muestra todos los datos excepto en el checkbox es decir(si yo activo el checkbox y guardo ,cuando pongo mostrar el checkbox que active y guarde me debería salir activado)

mi codigo html es

```
<fieldset class="cabezal"> 
    <br>
    <input type="Checkbox" name="Checkbox1" id="Checkbox1" value="1">               
    <label class="INSPECCIONES">CARROCERIA/CAPOT</label>
    <input type="text" id="prioridad1" name="prioridad1" placeholder="prioridad" class="prioridad" onkeypress="return unoaltres(event)" onchange="return return unoaltres(event);"
    onKeyUp="validar_prioridad_color('prioridad1');return limitar('prioridad1',1)"  onKeyDown="return limitar('prioridad1',1)" value="<?php echo $varprioridad1?>" >

    <input type="text" id="comentario1" name="comentario1" placeholder="comentario" class="comentario" value="<?php echo $varcomentario1?>">
</body>
</html>
```

mi funcion php es

```
                if (isset($_POST['codigo'])) 
        {
            $codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
            /*echo $licencia;*/
        }

        while ($codigoid = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
        $ccc=$codigoid['insp_codigo'];

        if($ccc<1){ 
        echo "<script> alert('no hay registro de la inspeccion');</script>";

    }
    else 
    {
        $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `inspecciones` where insp_estado=1 and insp_placa='$placa' and insp_detalle='$l1' ");

        $res=($sql);
        while ($resul=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $varplaca=$resul[3];
        $Checkbox1=$resul[7];
        $varprioridad1=$resul[9];
        $varcomentario1=$resul[10]; 


        # code...
    }

    if ($Checkbox1=="1"){
    $Checkbox1=="$Checkbox1.cheked";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el atributo **checked** al checkbox para decirle que está activo, simplemente reemplaza la siguiente línea

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox1" id="Checkbox1" <?php ($Checkbox1 == 1 ? 'checked' : '') ?> value="1">
```

y elimina de tu código PHP

```
if ($Checkbox1=="1"){
    $Checkbox1=="$Checkbox1.cheked";
```